# Did production of "The Adventures of Milo and Otis" involve a dramatically high rate of animal deaths?

Tags: zoology, movies, japan

A rumor has circulated on the internet for quite some time that there were many animal cruelty violations in the process of making the movie, [The Adventures of Milo and Otis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097050/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), including the deaths of over 30 animals.  Unfortunately, it seems like information to prove/disprove this is lacking.  Is there any definitive evidence to support or refute this claim.

[This article](http://subversify.com/2013/01/17/no-country-for-dead-dogs/) highlights the rumor, but fails to provide any real evidence one way or the other.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Milo_and_Otis#Animal_cruelty_allegations

Comment: "Animal deaths" is rather broad. I'm sure the Craft Services arm of many productions involve more than 30 chicken deaths. I am sure the fire scene in Gone With The Wind involved way more than 30 insect deaths.

Comment: @Oddthinking [some animals are more equal than others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rumours have never been able to be confirmed. [American Humane Association](http://web.archive.org/web/20010531234131/http://www.ahafilm.org/oldmovies1/theadventures/) have tried though, [without luck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Milo_and_Otis).

> We have tried through humane people in Japan, and through another Japanese producer to determine if these rumors are true or not but everything has led to a dead end.[1](http://web.archive.org/web/20010531234131/http://www.ahafilm.org/oldmovies1/theadventures/)

[Here are some of the deleted clips](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=goix8a6xMok#t=80) that were removed from the American release of the movie.

I linked to a specific time when a black bear attacks the little pug. In other clips the cat is being thrown off a cliff, and being attacked by a snake. Many of the scenes just looks too brutal, too real, to have been faked. Some can be done with well trained animals etc, but this is the [concern many other have had about the movie as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Milo_and_Otis).

> Kent said her organization had a number of complaints from people who had seen the film and were concerned that it could not have been made without cruelty. [ 1 ]

[ 1 ] *Gillespie, P. (April 15, 1990). "Cat Cruelty Claim Over Kids' Movie" The Sunday Mail*